# Returning a 2 dimentional array to be used in multiple events

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to have a 2d array read a text file then return the array so I can display it, modify it and so on.  I can't seem to figure out the

> 'No overload to method 'AdvisorList' takes 0 arguments'

no matter what I put in the `()` of `t.AdvisorList()`.

```
namespace Advisor_and_Student
{
    class Advisor
    {
        public String[][] AdvisorList(string[][] AdvisorArray)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\advisor.txt");
            AdvisorArray = lines.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
            return AdvisorArray;
        }
    }
}


    private void btnAdvisorAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Advisor t = new Advisor();
        string[][] AArray = t.AdvisorList();
        int j = AArray.GetLength(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < j; i++)
        {
            lbAdvisor.Items.Add(AArray[i][0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post a sanitized example line or two from your `advisor.txt` file?

Comment: `t.AdvisorList();` should be: `string [][]foo; t.Advisorlist(foo);`   I doubt you need to both input and output the array given your description however.  The only "thing" you can put in and satisfy the 0 parameter call is no thing (nothing).  e.g. in C++ `void foo(void){}`

Comment: The text file looks like: First Name, Last Name, Department  Then each line is a new entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't making use of the `AdvisorArray` parameter, you should change your method to not include it.

```
public string[][] AdvisorList()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\advisor.txt");
    var advisorArray = lines.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    return advisorArray;
}
```

With this, `t.AdvisorList()` should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing this might be some appropriate reading material on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173114.aspx